# Firebase Functions with other hostings

Tags: angular, firebase, web-hosting, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to use firebase functions from not only firebase hosting?

For example i will want to use hosting on iPage or siteground or anything else, is it possible to still use firebase functions, currently using it for sitemap.

If not possible to use it, any good idea how to replace generating sitemap?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call Cloud Functions from any web page, no matter where it is hosted.

But the integration between Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions that is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) directs traffic from Firebase Hosting to Cloud Functions, and allows you to set cache headers for the resulting dynamic content. This integration is only possible between Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions. It is **not** available with other hosting providers.

Comment: Thank you. Well then i need to find other way to dynamicly generate sitemap

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call your cloud functions from other places than "Firebase Hosting", so for instance you want to create a public API with Cloud Functions, that is possible.